# InputFields don't appear on some parts of the page, even though they do elsewhere

Tags: visualforce, inputfield, pageblocksection, apexinputfield, pageblocksectionitem

I have a visualforce page which has a couple page block sections (under pageblock > form), and is meant to have inputs within those sections. For some reason, the input fields will appear in the first pageblocksection but not the second.

```
    <apex:page controller="RecurringEvents_Controller">
<apex:form ><apex:pageBlock >
    <apex:pageBlockButtons >
        <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!Save}"/>
        <apex:commandButton value="Delete" action="{!Delete_x}"/>
        <apex:commandButton value="Toggle Active Status" action="{!toggleActive}"/>

        <apex:outputPanel >Current Event Recurrence: &nbsp;
            <apex:selectList value="{!EventRecurrenceID}" multiselect="false" size="1">
                <apex:selectOptions value="{!eventList}"/>
                <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!reload}"/>
            </apex:selectList></apex:outputPanel>
    </apex:pageBlockButtons>

    <apex:pageMessages />

    <apex:pageBlockSection title="Event Information">
        <apex:inputField value="{!eventRecurrence.name}"/>

        <apex:outputField value="{!eventRecurrence.Active__c}" />

    </apex:pageBlockSection>

    <apex:pageBlockSection title="Recurrence Information" columns="2">


        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem dataStyle="width:1%" labelStyle="width:1%" >
            <apex:selectRadio layout="pageDirection">
                <apex:selectOption itemvalue="1"/>
                <apex:selectOption itemvalue="2"/>
            </apex:selectRadio>
        </apex:pageblocksectionitem>
        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem dataStyle="padding:15px">
            <inputField value="{!eventRecurrence.name}"/>
            On day 
            <inputField value="{!eventRecurrence.Day__c}"/> 
            of every 
            <inputField value="{!eventRecurrence.Number_of_Months__c}"/> 
            month(s)
            <br/>


        </apex:pageblocksectionitem>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock></apex:form>
```

When I run the page I get this out
[image: incorrectly rendered]
So the question is, have I gone insane, or has Salesforce? What is causing the second pageblocksection to omit the input fields?

FYI I've tried removing all code in the second page block section except for a single inputfield for the name of the event recurrence object, removed the columns declaration, everything. Still doesn't render anything. So even if I make the second page block section the same as the first, it still fails to render correctly.

Edit: added a more explicit question.

Furthermore, when I inspect the rendered page, the areas where the inputfields should be there are indeed input tags, however the values are blanks.

All of the fields in the inputfields are being grabbed by SOQL in the controller, and the variable eventRecurrence is a public variable.

Comment: did you try by removing this styling on the pageblocksection if they appear at right places? dataStyle="width:1%" labelStyle="width:1%"

Comment: do you have permission to those inputFields?

Comment: Yeah, I removed the whole pageblocksectionitem with the radio buttons, even the other inputs, leaving only one input for the Name, with no change in behavior.

Comment: I do have permission, as you can see the Name and Active fields are rendering admirably'

Comment: can you paste the complete vf page? are there any other stylesheets that you are loading into the page

Comment: I've edited my post to include the whole page. Nothing fancy like that, the controller isn't doing much either beyond grabbing the record from the DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missed the **apex: namespace** in your inputfield here, also you are wrapping more than 2 child elements inside the pageblocksectionitem. once you add the apex: namespace the page may complaint that you have more than 2 child elements, which you may have to resolve by removing the apex:pageblocksectionitem wrapping the 3 fields (or) split them into 2 apex:pageblocksectionitem  to render the 3 input fields.

**Change this from:**

```
<inputField value="{!eventRecurrence.name}"/>
            On day 
            <inputField value="{!eventRecurrence.Day__c}"/> 
            of every 
            <inputField value="{!eventRecurrence.Number_of_Months__c}"/> 
            month(s)
```

**To:**

```
<apex:inputField value="{!eventRecurrence.name}"/>
                On day 
                <apex:inputField value="{!eventRecurrence.Day__c}"/> 
                of every 
                <apex:inputField value="{!eventRecurrence.Number_of_Months__c}"/> 
                month(s)
```

Comment: Thank you! Sometimes all it takes is someone over your shoulder I suppose.

Comment: Blame it on friday and move on :D

Comment: To be technical, it's not a "tag", it's a "namespace". Definitely a nice find, though; it's amazing how easy it is to miss something like that.

Comment: @sfdcfox corrected :) and for my defense, I am  blaming it on friday too.